# Como remover um atributo CSS com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

No jQuery, é possívei adicionar um atributo em um elemento através da função `attr`. É possível também remover um atributo através da função `removeAttr`.

E quando eu defino um atributo do `css` através da função `$.css`? Como faço para remover?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A solução mais simples seria zerar o elemento:

```
$.css("background-color", ""); // exemplo com background-color
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(function(){
  var contador = 0;
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    if(contador == 0)
    {
      $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
      contador = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).css("background-color", "");
      contador = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">Exemplo</button>
```

Fonte: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/jquery-remove-style-added-with-css-function#comment31826423_4036868)

Comment: [Relacionado ao SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/jquery-remove-style-added-with-css-function#comment31826423_4036868), hehe

Comment: Sim, Sim eu estava colocando na resposta junto com o exemplo kk

Comment: Obrigado. Alguém vai se beneficiar disso :D

Answer (score 14):

Remover um atributo CSS:

`$(el).css("color", "");`

Remover vários atributos CSS:

```
$(el).css({
   "color": "",
   "background-color": "",
   "outline": "",
});
```

Comment: achei essa interessante, hein